# How to load jQuery before DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, dom, document

I want to load some jQuery code before the DOM is ready. I want to make a flash file transparant as the DOM loads. I was going to use something like this but Flash is initilized before the DOM loads.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('object:not(:has(wmode))').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('wmode', 'transparent');
        jQuery(this).prepend('<param name="wmode" value="transparent">');
        jQuery(this).children('embed').attr('wmode', 'transparent');
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

---

### EDIT

Hey guys, thanks for the help, Basically, The flash content is coming from our Advertisement Manager, which stupidly enough, doesn't allow direct editing of the HTML, as to add the required wmode attributed into the specific tags...

So Javascript is my only option...

Comment: so you want to manipulate the DOM before the DOM loads?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. Is there any way?

Comment: what Hunter means is how can you manipulate something that isnt loaded? if you want the flash to be edited you'll have to do it in the HTML itself. later you can edit it with jquery to be 'normal'

Comment: Hmm, difficult. Not sure whether `wmode` can be set afterwards at all without re-creating the whole Flash movie. That would be worth a separate question IMO, what you are asking here is a paradox in itself

Answer (score 3):

`ready()` is the earliest point at which you can safely access arbitrary DOM elements.

You could put a `script` block directly after you declare the `object` tag: That should work, you will have access to the `object` element.

However, I don't think even that will help you: As far as I know, Flash won't accept a JavaScript-side changing of the `wmode` parameter anyway.

You would have to put `wmode.transparent` into the HTML, or create the Flash movies dynamically when the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript before the dom is loaded will yield to unpredictable results.
Modify your html code as you wish, but do not use javascript.

Comment: only if the JS is used to access the DOM (which is the case in the context of the question of course)

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to construct the object or embed element on dom ready event:

```
<div id="flash"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
   var htm= '<object ...><param name="some" value="val" ... /></object>';
   $('#flash').html(htm);

});
```